# Update Product Quantity on Hand when Order Products are Added to Order

Tags: order

We don't use opportunities or opp products.  We use order and order products.  I would like to update "Total on Hand" on the Product when products are added to the order and the order is activated.  "Total on Hand" would be reduced by the order product quantity for that product.  I have tried to use process builder to accomplish this but can't figure it out.  I can't get workflow/field update to work either because of the relationship between order, order product and product.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Presumably you are using pricebooks? have you tried traversing the OrderItem -> PricebookEntry -> Product2 relationship?